# When using codeigniter, can I load content to a view from different controllers?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have 2 controller files: login.php and tables.php.

login.php loads the view I want:

```
function locales(){
        $data['main_content'] = 'negocios';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
```

however inside that view I am using:

```
<?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
            <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

which makes reference to the tables.php controller:

```
class Tables extends Controller{

    function createTables(){
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/tables/createTables';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('usuarios')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('usuarios', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    }
}
```

Can I accomplish what I'm trying to do? if so, how? Also, I know it's not recommended to access the DB directly in the controller but I'm doing this just for practice sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to access to database directly from controller? In my opinion, this is not a good practice. The MVC patterns is designed to separate controll from views and data.

Quoting wikipedia:

> **The model manages the behavior and
>   data of the application domain**,
>   responds to requests for information
>   about its state (usually from the
>   view), and responds to instructions to
>   change state (usually from the
>   controller). In event-driven systems,
>   the model notifies observers (usually
>   views) when the information changes so
>   that they can react.
>
> **The view renders the model into a form
>   suitable for interaction**, typically a
>   user interface element. Multiple views
>   can exist for a single model for
>   different purposes. A viewport
>   typically has a one to one
>   correspondence with a display surface
>   and knows how to render to it.
>
> The **controller receives input and
>   initiates a response by making calls
>   on model objects**. A controller accepts
>   input from the user and instructs the
>   model and viewport to perform actions
>   based on that input.

I'll try to create a model called 'Tables' and inside of it put this:

```
class Tables extends Model{

    function createTables(){
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/tables/createTables';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('usuarios')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        return $this->db->get('usuarios', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    }
}
```

Then, your Login Controller could be:

```
function locales(){
   $data['main_content'] = 'negocios';
   $this->load->model('tables');
   $data['records'] = $this->tables->createTables();
   $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

Now, you can modify the view:

```
// all your code...
<?php 
echo $records; 
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
// more code...
```

If you don't need to call `$this->tables->createTables()` everytime, you should modify the controller:

```
function locales(){
   $data['main_content'] = 'negocios';
   $this->load->model('tables');
   if(yourcondition)
      $data['records'] = $this->tables->createTables();
   $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

And your view:

```
// all your code...
<?php 
if(isset($records))
   echo $records; 
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
// more code...
```

Comment: This is an intelligent answer but the separation for this project is horrible. Models should be dumb and only interact with data, but ths createTables method needs to know the current URL, the controller name and all sorts of other things. Models should not contain this kind of logic anyway.

Comment: @Phil Agree with you. We need to see all the architecture to create a good design. But this is another question :). Vote up to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're connecting to dots correctly in your question.  You cannot directly reference all controllers within views.

To more fully understand what you are typing, the `$this` keyword you are using in both your controller and view files makes reference to (for all intensive purposes*) the controller you are using, so it would not make sense to call `$this->{controller}->function()` because you would be calling the controller of the controller.

I believe you are attempting to implement an [HMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control) structure.  There has been some work done to implement this in CodeIgniter through [Modular Extensions](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC/)

But generally Vanilla codeigniter is 1 Controller at a time, but that controller can load many views and/or models.

---

*I know it is the CI instance, but the CI instance for all intensive purposes ***IS*** the controller

Comment: He is right, you want to use HMVC to achieve this, or create some libraries. The current accepted answer is teaching you bad practices.

Comment: @Phil We need to see all the code. If the user only puts a little bit, it's impossible to know if he's organizing good his project.